# How to convert Dolby Vision to SDR/HDR and sustain metadata?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-editor

Now I have a Dolby Vison streaming with Filmmaker mode which is from DV cert. lab. I want to convert this streaming file to SDR and HDR. I'm an outdoor for ffmpeg. Who can help me to write a ffmpeg command to reach the target? Very appreciate it.

PS: I use this command, but it only execute successfully when input video file is HDR.
ffmpeg -i HDR.mp4  -vf zscale=t=linear:npl=100,format=gbrpf32le,zscale=p=bt709,tonemap=tonemap=hable:desat=0,zscale=t=bt709:m=bt709:r=tv,format=yuv420p -c:v h264 -crf 19 -preset ultrafast output.mp4

Filmmaker Mode is a standard from the UHD Alliance. It enables the TV to display the content of a movie or
television show precisely as intended by the filmmaker. Filmmaker Mode disables all postprocessing and
preserves the correct aspect ratios, colors, and frame rates.